# how to update android contacts

Tags: android

hello
i am updating contacts name and number , the code for the above is

```
Uri workUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.clear();
values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,""+editname);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,""+editno);
getContentResolver().update(workUri, values, null, null);
```

But it is not working.
Can anyone suggest me where i m wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the error you're getting ?

Comment: Ther is no error bt the fields are not updating.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding the following to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Except the `TIMES_CONTACTED`, `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED`, `STARRED`, `CUSTOM_RINGTONE` and `SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL` fields, all other fields in contacts are read only

See this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

The contacts content provider works in a different way..

Before you call the update, find the ID of the Row which you need to update.

Then you need to create a Uri object pointing the row and call update with that URI.